# Как я могу исполнять бесконечную функцию параллельно обработке запросов в django?

Tags: python, django, многопоточность, requests, backend

Я недавно занимаюсь бэкендом на django, и я столкнулся с проблемой параллельного исполнения некоторой функции, которая выполняется все время работы сервера, но при этом мне нужно, чтобы параллельно с выполнением этой функции я мог переходить на другие страницы моего веб приложения. Я так понимаю, мне нужно использовать библиотеку thred для многопоточной работы приложения, но в данный момент я просто запускаю бесконечный цикл, а когла перехожу на другие стр, то приложение приостанавливает выполнение функции

Comment: что делает эта функция?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно так

```
def foo():
    while True:
        print(1)
        sleep(2)

t = Thread(target=foo, daemon=True)
t.start()
```

добавить в один из файлов которые импортит django при старте